# Creating a multiple data frames in FOR-LOOP

Tags: r, for-loop, dataframe

I would like to create data frames from a FOR-LOOP in R.

Basically, I would like to do something like this:

```
for (i in 1:3) { x"i"= 1+i}
```

In this case, I would like to get 3 dataframes:

- x1 that would only contain 2
- x2 that would only contain 3
- x3 that would only contain 4

Is there a way to do this in **R**?

Comment: (1) Why do you want data frames to store a single number? (2) Is it possible to use a list instead of multiple data frames?

Comment: This is just to simplify the question. Basically, I need different subsets of a dataframe and I would like to store them in x"i" data frames for future use.

Answer (score 9):

```
for (i in 1:3) {
  assign(paste0("x", i), i + 1)
}
```

This will create objects `x1`, `x2`, and `x3` with the values of `i + 1`, i.e., 2-4.

Comment: I think the OP want `x1` to be 2, `x2=3` and `x3=4`, so your assigning should be `assign(paste0("x", i), i+1)`, right?

Comment: @Jilber Right. I modified the answer.